# CustomValidator doesnt display a message unless I use a validation summary

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to output a message in case if an invalid date was supplied.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RegistrationFromTextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="RegistrationFromTextBox2" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="NewMailingItem" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The date is invalid"></asp:CustomValidator>

      protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime temp;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, out temp))
            {
                args.IsValid =true;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            args.IsValid = false;

        }
    }
```

I expect the output message to be located near the field.

Instead I get no response, even though the function works. I only get the error message if I put a validation summary to my form.

Is there away display the message without the validation summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there away display the message without the validation summary?

You will need to use `Text` attribute instead of `ErrorMessage`.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" 
   ControlToValidate="RegistrationFromTextBox2" 
   OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" 
   ValidationGroup="NewMailingItem" 
   runat="server"
   Text="The date is invalid">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

**FYI:** If you just want to validate date, you could use `CompareValidator` or [Ajax Control Toolkit's Calendar](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RegistrationFromTextBox2" runat="server"
    placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator
    ID="RegistrationFromCompareValidator" runat="server"
    Type="Date"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    ControlToValidate="RegistrationFromTextBox2"
    Text="The date is invalid">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: hmm.. thanks.  I know about the compare validator. I need to use a custom validator.

Comment: Also you might want to include syntax for Display="Dynamic" if you won't want the layout to contain a space/linebreak for the message unless the message is being displayed.